# Why is java compiler not complaining about "\s"?

Tags: java, java-15

Tried it on openjdk version "15" 2020-09-15

Following simple line

`String str = "\s";`

According to official documentation of [list of escape characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), \s is not defined.

Spring tool suite does not show compilation error for '\s' nor does when I compile on command line using maven. Any other characters such as \p result into following error which matches with official documentation.

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  "  '  \ )

Why doesn't java compiler complain about \s? Printing the resultant string on console indicates that it's outputting space character (0x20), so looks like it's recognizing it, but just not documented.

Comment: If you print out the String what happens?

Comment: ...because that page was written for JDK8 and even says that at the top of the page.

Comment: New escape sequences added in Java 15 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html

Comment: @AnikethMalyala, it's in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a new escape sequence in Java 15:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html

The tutorial you linked to is for Java 8, but you are on JDK 15.

Comment: Shouldn't error message mention it? It still says valid escapes from older list

Comment: @user871199 [The language specification under 3.10.7. Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7) mentions "s" as a valid escape character, so there will be no error message.

Comment: @Scratte, but error message is very explicit - exactly as in the post. Minor issue, but still issue. If error message is giving a list, then one tends to assume it's a complete list.

Comment: @user871199 I expect the explanation is that a developer forgot to update the error message. You could try to contact OpenJDK and see if you can submit a bug-report on the message.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` is a valid escape sequence in Java SE 15 as specified in the [`String#translateEscapes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#translateEscapes()) documentation:

[image]

The error message that you have mentioned is definitely a bug.